# Trello Manatee adding attachment

Tags: c#, attachment, trello, manatee.trello

I am trying to add an attachment to a pre-created Trello card using Manatee API.

This is how I create the card, I have no problems with it:

```
        /// <summary>
        ///  This function creates a card on Trello <Board_Name> board, into the list named <List_Name>.
        ///  It creates a card with the title and descrition comming from the function which is called
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="subject"> This is the subject (Title) of the ticket </param>
        /// <param name="body"> This is the body section (description) of the ticket </param>
        public string createTrelloTicketCard(string subject, string body)
        {
            string cardId = null;
            trelloToken = adminTrelloToken; // define who is creating the card

            Run(() =>
            {
                TrelloProcessor.WaitForPendingRequests = true;
                var board = new Board(<Board_ID>); // board id
                var list = board.Lists[5]; // The sixth list of the board 

                var card = list.Cards.Add(subject); // create a card with the subject from tblTasks
                cardId = card.Id; // get the created card ID
                card.Description = body; // define description from tblTasks
                
                // Add all the IT members to the card
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItMembersInBoard; i ++)
                {
                    card.Members.Add(board.Members[i]); 
                }
            });

            return cardId;
        }
```

This is how I try adding attachment to the card. The problem occurs in this function:

```
public void InsertAttachementIntoTrelloCard(string cardId, byte[] buffer, string name)
        {
            Run(() =>
            {
                TrelloProcessor.WaitForPendingRequests = true;

                var board = new Board(<Board_ID>); // board id
                
                var list = board.Lists[5]; // The sixth list of the board 
                
                var card = new Card(cardId); // specify the card that the file is going to be attached
                card.Description = "Test3";

                card.Attachments.Add(buffer, name); // Here I get the error
            });
        }
```

When I try attaching the file I get an error starting with this sentence:

***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

I am pretty sure the created byte array is correct and when I remove that line the program ends without any errors. Am I using the wrong method ?

Here is the Stack Trace:

> ex.Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>
> ex.StackTrace = "      at
> Manatee.Trello.Internal.DataAccess.JsonRepository.PrepRequest(IRestRequest
> request, TrelloAuthorization auth) in
> e:\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello\Internal\DataAccess\JsonRepository.cs:line
> 79    at
> Manatee.Trello.Internal.DataAccess.JsonRepository.BuildRequest(TrelloAuthorization
> auth, Endpoint endpoint, IDictionary`2 parameters) in
> e:\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello\Internal\DataAccess\JsonRepository.cs:line
> 74    at
> Manatee.Trello.Internal.DataAccess.JsonRepository.Execute[T](TrelloAuthorization
> auth, Endpoint endpoint, IDictionary'2 parameters) in
> e:\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello\Internal\DataAccess\JsonRepository.cs:line
> 46    at Manatee.Trello.AttachmentCollection.Add(Byte[] data, String
> name) in
> e:\Projects\Manatee.Trello\Manatee.Trello\AttachmentCollection.cs:line
> 112    at
> Live.XmlFax.XmlFaxForm.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__7()
> in c:\Users\arif.gencosmanoglu\Documents\EnteringC#\Printer
> Project\XmlFax\XmlFaxForm.cs:line 2035    at
> Live.XmlFax.XmlFaxForm.Run(Action action) in
> c:\Users\arif.gencosmanoglu\Documents\EnteringC#\Printer
> Project\XmlFax\XmlFaxForm.cs:line 1724    at
> Live.XmlFax.XmlFaxForm.InsertAttachementIntoTrelloCard(String cardId,
> Byte[] buffer, String name) in
> c:\Users\arif.gencosmanoglu\Documents\EnteringC#\Printer
> Project\XmlFax\XmlFaxForm.cs:line 2023    at
> Live.XmlFax.XmlFaxForm.ReadTicketEmail() in
> c:\Users\arif.gencosmanoglu\Documents\EnteringC#\Printer
> Project\XmlFax\XmlFaxForm.cs:line 1981    at
> Live.XmlFax.XmlFaxForm.cmdItTicket_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> in c:\Users\arif.gencosmanoglu\Documents\EnteringC#\Printer
> Project\XmlFax\XmlFaxForm.cs:line 1884

Comment: @GrantWinney yes, I first create a card with no attachments, then i call my function using the created card id, to add an attachment.

Comment: @GrantWinney does this mean I am using the wrong method to add attachment ?

Comment: I am the creator of Manatee.Trello.  Can you update with the stack trace, please?  You may have found a hidden bug.  I can't see that you're doing anything wrong.  This generally works for me (works on my box! haha)

Comment: @GrantWinney, `Attachments` is never null.  The collection is created upon Card construction.

Comment: I added the stack trace to my post. Thanks for your interests.

Comment: I also added the function which creates the card instance.

Comment: @0014, what version of Manatee.Trello are you using?  I'm having trouble replicating the error.

Comment: @gregsdennis the installed version is 1.3.0. Should I upgrade it to v 1.4.1 ?

Comment: @0014, please upgrade and try again.

Comment: @gregsdennis I considered upgrading it, however I have a lot of coding done using your API. They wont be effected right ?

Comment: There aren't any breaking changes between those versions.

Comment: @gregsdennis Now I even cant create a card hehe. I get error on this line.  `var serializer = new ManateeSerializer();` I shall try it later maybe by looking at the latest examples.

Comment: Please also upgrade Manatee.Trello.ManateeJson and Manatee.Trello.RestSharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where the problem is.  Every path to that point in the stack trace has all of the dependencies covered, and that error shouldn't happen.

Please make sure you have the latest of the following Nuget packages:

- Manatee.Trello
- Manatee.Trello.ManateeJson
- Manatee.Trello.RestSharp